# dbConnect to Postgres gives strange error not allowing me to connect

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql, rpostgres

I am trying to connect to my localhost Postgres DB within R to further read/write tables. The server is running in the background which I'm monitoring in the background. I'm using the RPostgreSQL library.

```
pg <- dbDriver(drvName = "PostgreSQL")
    
con <- dbConnect(drv = pg, dbname = "test", 
                 host = "localhost", 
                 port = 5432, 
                 user = "postgres", 
                 password = "1234")

dbListTables(con)
```

Just running the dbConnect part gives a strange message reading:

```
ØJI)
```

Further running the dbListTables function gives:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 'dbWriteTable': object 'con' not found
```

I can't figure out what I am missing.

**Edit: I think I'm not using the RPostgreSQL library correctly. Using RPostgres worked perfectly now.**

Comment: This is interesting, as it seems to be the first I've seen where `RPostgres` and `RPostgreSQL` differ at connection-attempt. Glad it's working for you with the `RPostgres` package.

Comment: Same here, Windows 11, PostgreSQL 14, with ```RPostgres``` no problems https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RPostgres with ```RPostgreSQL``` the strange error ·°])